# Why doesn't my carousel work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

My carousel doesn't slide automatically. I can click through my pictures only.
The strange thing is that at one point I could of sworn it did work. I just dont know what I could have changed since.

Here's my code:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="slider" class="span5" style="padding:15px;" >
    <div class="carousel slide" style="border:#fff 3px solid;" id="treatments">
    <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
    <img src="img/sliderpic1.jpg" alt="massage">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    <img src="img/sliderpic2.jpg" alt="pedicure">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
    <img src="img/sliderpic3.jpg" alt="waxing">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#treatments" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a href="#treatments" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">&raquo;</a>
    </div>
    <img src="img/logos.png" class="img-rounded">
    </div>


Then just before the close body tag:

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 1200
  });
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for all of your help, it's much appreciated!

Comment: try adding the `<script src>` tags before the code, but preserve the `$('carousel').carousel({...` call right where it is

Answer (score 2):

You're setting up the carousel before you've included jQuery. Swap the `<script>` tags around:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 1200
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what about the `$(document).ready(function()...` call? don't you need it to start the script when the whole page is ready?

Comment: @luchosrock only if the `<script>` tag is in the `<head>` or before the elements it is amending have been loaded. If the script is just before the `</body>` - as in this case - the ready handler can be omitted.

Comment: thanks, didn't know about that since i always keep the source and js script in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: I do too, however this method will result in marginally faster loading, and possibly avoid FOUC problems.